# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String problem

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a quiz app
i add the Question on my firebase Realtie Database
when i want to see it show me this error

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String"

in this page :

> com.quiz.footwikiquiz.questions.QuestionsActivity$1.onDataChange(QuestionsActivity.java:72)

heres my code for QuestionsActivity :

```
public class QuestionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

    private TextView question,noIndicator;
    private FloatingActionButton bookmarkbtn;
    private LinearLayout optioncontainer;
    private Button shareBtn,nextBtn;
    private int count=0;
    private List<QuestionsModel> list;
    private int position =0;
    private int score=0;
    private int setNo;
    private String category;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar11);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        question = findViewById(R.id.question);
        noIndicator = findViewById(R.id.no_indicator);
        bookmarkbtn = findViewById(R.id.bookmark_btn);
        optioncontainer = findViewById(R.id.option_container);
        shareBtn = findViewById(R.id.share_btn);
        nextBtn = findViewById(R.id.next_btn);


        category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
        setNo = getIntent().getIntExtra("setNo",1);

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        myRef.child("SETS").child(category).child("Questions").orderByChild("setNo").equalTo(setNo).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    list.add(snapshot.getValue(QuestionsModel.class));
                }
                if (list.size() > 0) {

                    for (int i=0 ; i<4 ;i++) {
                        optioncontainer.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                checkAnswer((Button)v);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    playAnim(question,0,list.get(position).getQuestion());
                    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            nextBtn.setEnabled(false);
                            nextBtn.setAlpha(0.7f);
                            enableoption(true);
                            position++;
                            if (position == list.size()) {
                                return;
                            }
                            count= 0;
                            playAnim(question,0,list.get(position).getQuestion());
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(QuestionsActivity.this, "no questions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(QuestionsActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });




    }

    private void playAnim(final View view , final int value , final String data) {

        view.animate().alpha(value).scaleX(value).scaleY(value).setDuration(500).setStartDelay(100).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                if (value ==0 && count<4) {
                    String option ="";
                    if (count == 0) {
                        option = list.get(position).getOptionA();
                    } else if (count == 1) {
                        option = list.get(position).getOptionB();
                    } else if (count == 2) {
                        option = list.get(position).getOptionC();
                    } else if (count == 3) {
                        option = list.get(position).getOptionD();
                    }
                    playAnim(optioncontainer.getChildAt(count),0,option);
                    count++;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if (value ==0 ) {
                    try {
                        ((TextView)view).setText(data);
                        noIndicator.setText(position+1+"/"+list.size());
                    }catch (ClassCastException ex){
                        ((Button)view).setText(data);
                    }
                    view.setTag(data);
                    playAnim(view,1,data);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void checkAnswer(Button selectedoption) {
        enableoption(false);
        nextBtn.setEnabled(true);
        nextBtn.setAlpha(1);
        if (selectedoption.getText().toString().equals(list.get(position).getCorrectAns())) {
            score++;
            selectedoption.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50")));
        } else {
            selectedoption.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")));
            Button correctoption = optioncontainer.findViewWithTag(list.get(position).getCorrectAns());
            correctoption.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50")));
        }
    }

    private void enableoption(boolean enable){
        for (int i=0 ; i<4 ;i++) {
            optioncontainer.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(enable);
            if (enable) {
                optioncontainer.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#989898")));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the QuestionModel code :

```
public class QuestionsModel {

    private String optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD, correctAns;
    private int setNo;
    private String question;

    public QuestionsModel(){

    }

    public QuestionsModel(String question, String optionA, String optionB, String optionC, String optionD, String correctAns,int setNo) {
        this.setNo = setNo;
        this.question = question;
        this.optionA = optionA;
        this.optionB = optionB;
        this.optionC = optionC;
        this.optionD = optionD;
        this.correctAns = correctAns;

    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getOptionA() {
        return optionA;
    }

    public void setOptionA(String optionA) {
        this.optionA = optionA;
    }

    public String getOptionB() {
        return optionB;
    }

    public void setOptionB(String optionB) {
        this.optionB = optionB;
    }

    public String getOptionC() {
        return optionC;
    }

    public void setOptionC(String optionC) {
        this.optionC = optionC;
    }

    public String getOptionD() {
        return optionD;
    }

    public void setOptionD(String optionD) {
        this.optionD = optionD;
    }

    public String getCorrectAns() {
        return correctAns;
    }

    public void setCorrectAns(String correctAns) {
        this.correctAns = correctAns;
    }

    public int getSetNo() {
        return setNo;
    }

    public void setSetNo(int setNo) {
        this.setNo = setNo;
    }
}
```

this is my firebase

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing the answers (`optionA`, `optionB`, etc) as numbers in `Question1`, but you are trying to cast them to a string.

If you're directly accessing the `DataSnapshot` value you can get the object with:

```
myRef.child("SETS").child(category).child("Questions").orderByChild("setNo").equalTo(setNo).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i("Database", snapshot.child("optionA").getValue();
        }
```

If you want to put the options into your Java class, the only way you can do that is by declaring all answers as `Object`:

```
public class QuestionsModel {

    private Object optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD, correctAns;
    private int setNo;
    private String question;

    public QuestionsModel(){

    }

    public QuestionsModel(String question, String optionA, String optionB, String optionC, String optionD, String correctAns,int setNo) {
        this.setNo = setNo;
        this.question = question;
        this.optionA = optionA;
        this.optionB = optionB;
        this.optionC = optionC;
        this.optionD = optionD;
        this.correctAns = correctAns;

    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public Object getOptionA() {
        return optionA;
    }

    public void setOptionA(Object optionA) {
        this.optionA = optionA;
    }

    public Object getOptionB() {
        return optionB;
    }

    public void setOptionB(Object optionB) {
        this.optionB = optionB;
    }

    public Object getOptionC() {
        return optionC;
    }

    public void setOptionC(Object optionC) {
        this.optionC = optionC;
    }

    public Object getOptionD() {
        return optionD;
    }

    public void setOptionD(Object optionD) {
        this.optionD = optionD;
    }

    public Object getCorrectAns() {
        return correctAns;
    }

    public void setCorrectAns(Object correctAns) {
        this.correctAns = correctAns;
    }

    public int getSetNo() {
        return setNo;
    }

    public void setSetNo(int setNo) {
        this.setNo = setNo;
    }
}
```

But in general I'd recommend fixing the type of the answers to `Question1` in the database, and storing them as string values.

Comment: Mr frank thanks for help i changed the stored answers to string but fixing this let me have attention to anither problem that the question doesn't show up (both questions didn't pop up just the answers